# NAND RAW access

Tags: filesystems, embedded, flash-memory

I'm working with a C++ application in an embedded systems running Linux. This device receives messages (small chunk of few bytes) and need to be stored in a non volatile memory in case of power failure. This worked well with another platform because a static RAM was available.

The problem on this platform is that we only have a NAND Flash to do this and we would like to append different message in the same block without having to erase the whole block before updating it with a new message ! Writing a file per messages is not a good solution because there can be a lot of them ! Moreover, this must be efficient and should be life sparing for the flash by avoiding too much erases ! What I would like to be able to do is writing byte after byte into the flash without worrying about bad blocks.

I found "[Petit FAT File System](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_p.html)" and I'm wondering if this would suite my needs ... ?

Could someone tell me if this is possible with "Petit FAT File System" or give me any suggestion on how to handle this ?

Thanks !

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677481/nand-flash-programming-granularity-of-writes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked into Petit file system, but your real limitation is the NAND flash. The manufacture data sheet will likely indicate how many writes you can successfully make to each block, before an erase is required. It's possible that there is no hard limit, but the integrity of the data will not be guaranteed after a max write count.

The answer depends on the process technology and flash cell design. For example, is it SLC or MLC NAND? SLC is going to be able to handle multiple block writes better.

Another question would be what type of flash controller is on your system? If it uses hardware ECC, then you might be limited by the controller, since 2nd writes will invalidate the ECC value of the 1st data write. If it is possible that you can do ECC calculations in software, then it comes back to the NAND limitation.

Small write support might be addressed in the data sheet, via a special set aside memory area that might be provided. So again, check the data sheet.

If you post a link, or indicate what hardware you are using, I can try and give you a more definite answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But to be honest, this is pretty low level for my knowledges and I think I will read a lot of documentation !
We are using our own platform based on an Ti ARM (http://focus.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/am1808.pdf) connected to this NAND flash (http://www.szyuda88.com/uploadfile/cfile/2011225135937123.pdf). It seems that there is a kind of controller on this flash and we can't have direct access to it ... Could you confirm ?

Comment: @mordang - Page 12 of the Flash datasheet states the max `Number of Partial Program Cycles` is 4.  This means you can write to a single Flash page 4 times before erasing it.  It is important to understand that you cannot overwrite any area of a page without erasing but you can write to previously unused addresses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with flash, there's no way around deleting it before writing. All flash memory works in that way. Depending on your real-time requirements and the size of the data, this may or may not be an issue. But since you are using embedded Linux, real-time is probably not a major concern for the application anyhow.

I don't see why you would need a complete file system to store a few bytes?! Why do you need an external memory for this in the first place, can't you write to the internal flash of the MCU? If you just need to store a few bytes, an MCU with on-chip eeprom/data flash would likely suit your needs the best.

Also, that flash circuit doesn't look too promising. First I find it mighty fishy that they don't type out the number of cycles nor the data retention but refer to the "gualification report". This might indicate that the the memory is of poor quality.
And the data sheet says year 2009 and Samsung. If I may be cynical, that probably means that the chip is already obsolete.  Samsung doesn't exactly have the best long-life reputation.

Comment: Not correct. You can perform multiple writes to a flash block. Erased block is all 0xFF. A flash write will pull bits down to 0x00. If you write 1st half of block, and leave 2nd half as 0xFF's, you can make another write to the second half. You can not write 0x00's, back to 0xFF's. That is what erase is for.

Comment: @Casey While that is true, it means nothing in the real world. Because you have to save everything present in the whole flash block in RAM before erasing, then alter some cells, then write the whole data back. The alternative is to make an eeprom emulation algorithm with segments, but those are awfully slow and non-deterministic, and shouldn't be used for anything beyond hobbyist projects. Therefore, always look at block erase size of flash memories, everything else is quite irrelevant.

Comment: I already explained why you don't need to use flash in a erase-write sequence. Partial writes allows you to emulate small block (512KB) writes on a large block (4KB) NAND device. It is very relevant in the real world, otherwise it would not be addressed in the data sheet. Depending on OP use case, implementing a partial write feature would extend the life of the flash by 400%. The determinism of the partial-write is determined by the manufactures specs. If you don't want to trust them, then that is up to the individual to decide.

Comment: @Casey That algorithm will only allow you to store the very same data on several locations in the same flash block. You are assuming that the application can afford to waste *huge* amounts of the flash to store the same data over and over in the same block. The access time has nothing to do with specs or even hardware, it is common sense: if I store the same data in several different memory locations, how can my program know which data type that is the correct one? *The program must search through the block with the "partial writes" each time you wish to access the data through Big O(n)!*

Comment: My original comment still stands. You may not think partial programming is useful, but here is Spansions take: "Partial page programming is important to file systems, providing a faster and easier way to man-age data in storage devices. It prevents the file system from programming a complete page every
time it needs to write or move data, helping the file system better utilize a page and increase performance reduced through the number of erase operations." -- http://bit.ly/evb9XC

Comment: Some flash devices can accommodate multiple writes to a flash block without an intervening erase if no write has to turn any zeroes into ones.  Many NAND flash devices, however, are much more limited.

Comment: @Lundin: For devices which support partial writes, and applications which need to make frequent changes to small parts of a block, it can be very helpful to use a mixture of full and incremental updates, especially if only a small portion of the data in the device needs such flexibility.  Use a "rolling set" of 4K erase blocks, and have the first 256 bytes represent a snapshot of 256 bytes worth of data, then use the remaining storage to hold four-byte records each of which holds an index and the value to be stored there, along with a checksum which can guarantee that...

Comment: ...a store of FF to offset FF won't look like blank data, and that no partial write will be mistaken for a complete one [Compute the nine-bit sum of the two data bytes, and store 5F minus the high five bits in one checksum byte, then write the data, then store AF minus the low four bits in the other].  Once the 4K block gets full, write a new snapshot of the 256 bytes of data into a new block; once that's done, the old block can be abandoned.  The net effect is that one can perform 950+ individual-byte updates for each erase cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you want to use raw flash.  Why not use something like JFFS2 or UBIFS on top of the MTD drive? Let the MTD driver manage the ECC while JFFS2 or UBIFS manages the wear-leveling.  Then just open one file and write to it whenever you need.

Comment: Because I wanted to avoid "rewriting" a whole block for updating only few bytes ... But as Casey said, as long as we change one byte, we have to change the ECC -> NAND limitation! Actually I don't think this is possible. We will definitly use files despite this is not good for the nand life time!

Comment: The filesystem layer will buffer the data until a block needs to be written (unless you sync it).  Even then most NAND chips have a RAM buffer that you write into before the block gets transferred to flash.  You simply write a byte at a time to the buffer.  When the buffer fills, you write it to the flash page.  But you don't (and shouldn't) manage this yourself.  That's what flash filesystems like JFFS2 and UBIFS are for.  However, if you really need to write only a byte at a time then maybe NAND isn't the write choice for your application.

Comment: Accessing raw flash gives control over what will happen if power is unexpectedly removed, especially if one also has a small secondary non-volatile memory device with more convenient write characteristics.  It's too bad NAND flash devices don't include a documented ability to expressly invalidate a row without erasing it, since that would allow robust protocols to be implemented much more efficiently without need of secondary storage.